# How to use monkeypatch in pytest to mock a function more than one time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, paramiko

The function that I want to test is something like this

```
def function(ssh_client):

    stdin1, stdout1, stderr1 = ssh_client.exec_command("first_command")
    stdout1 = stdout1.readlines()
    if stdout1:
        print("first_command_executed")
        
    stdin2, stdout2, stderr2 = ssh_client.exec_command("second_command")
    stdout = stdout.readlines()
    if stdout2:
        print("second_command_executed")
```

I'm trying to use monkeypatch in pytest to create unit test case for above function. like this.

```
def return_exec_command(*args, **kwargs):
        return "", data, ""

    monkeypatch.setattr(ssh_client, 'exec_command', return_exec_command)
```

But the question is, when it is been executed, this patch is returning same output both time. So, How can I create unit test for above function?

Comment: Just have `return_exec_command` return different output depending on its input?

Comment: Actually not depending on inputs(even not depend on command). Just need to return_exec_command return different output.

Comment: Use [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) with [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) instead. You can assign a list of values to `side_effect` that will be returned in subsequent calls.

Comment: Thank you @MrBeanBremen. Found a solution from pytest-mock  module.